# pagination not working in select2 plugin

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using select2 plugin. All are working well. but pagination is not working. Showing "Loading more results" at the end & it's disabled. I am confused what I am missing. Please guide. I have the file like:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js, https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css, https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js.

Here is my code:

```
$('.itemName').select2({
    placeholder : 'Select an item',
    ajax : {
        url : 'search_ajax.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        delay : 250,
        data : function (params) {
            return {
                term : params.term || '',
                page : params.page || 1
            }
        },
        processResults : function (data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 1;

            return {
                results : data.results,
                pagination : {
                    more : (params.page * 5) < data.total_count
                }
            };
        },
        cache : true
    }
});
```

Here is the json response:

```
{
    "total_count" : "10",
    "results" : [{
            "id" : "200",
            "text" : "Australian National University"
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing some file to include?